# How to avoid allocating memory for unused attributes

Tags: c++, class, memory

I have a `Message` class that hold all the possible elements a message can have:

```
class Message {
    int msg_id;
    int msg_length;

    char *username;
    char *password;
    char *usr_list;
    char *to;
    char *from;
    char *grp_name;
    int digit_1;
    int digit_2;
    char *msg;
};
```

But different message types have different body elements and to make an object out of it is wasting a lot of memory. For example, my program receives the following data:

```
Msg -> (1, name, password)
```

When the program reads a `1`, it creates a `Message` object, sets its name and password and forwards it to another class. Now the remaining attributes are empty and unused but still consume memory.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**
Will Visitor pattern help me in this case , I am not sure if targets such issues.

Comment: That's not a valid C++ `class` declaration.

Comment: Sounds like a case for using a `union` along with type information.

Comment: Most of your members are pointers, they don't take up much memory if you don't allocate anything for them.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... which in turns sounds like a case for `std::variant` (or its Boost doppelgänger) ;)

Comment: @Barmer I have copied it from class diagram, i Know how to declare class , it is just shown to you to tell how it looks

Comment: @Shahan - That doesn't contradict Barmar's comment about this not being valid C++ code.

Comment: try google::protobuf - it will give you all your requirements out of the box (high performance, small memory footprint)

Answer (score 6):

Since Basile's answer is the correct one in a global sense, I think that it is important to state the following.

If you are trying to implement a **communication protocol**, I would recommend using a commonly used data serialization library.

These libraries allow you to easily declare a communication protocol, they include support for such features and more and are supported by many different languages.

A full list of options can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

I have successfully used these ones in the past:

- Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)
- Google's [Flat Buffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

Answer (score 3):

Read about [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)s or *sum types*. Learn how to use [union types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), in particular follow the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and/or use [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Perhaps you'll need [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) with explicit calls to destructors. Prefer [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (see also [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)) to raw ones (and `std::string` to `char*`). Use `enum`s (or even [`enum class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)es) instead of bounded ids. Be familiar with [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

You could also try to define some class hierarchy so have several classes of messages ...

Spend a week reading some good [book on C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) before coding.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage C++'s inheritance and polymorphism.

Categorize different message types based on their attributes and create class hierarchy to represent them.

```
class Message
{
    public:
    // virtual methods to process the message

    private:
    // Attributes common to all the messages
};

class MessageType1: public Message
{
    public:
    // Methods to process the message

    private:
    //Attributes specific to Type1 messages
};

class MessageType2: public Message
{
    public:
    // Methods to process the message

    private:
    //Attributes specific to Type2 messages
};
```

Creating Message objects - You can implement a factory which aids creation of different messageType objects

```
class MessageFactory
{
    // Method to create MessageType1 object
    // Method to create MessageType2 object
};
```

Storing Message objects - You can use containers to store and iterate through different message objects using standard library APIs.

```
std::vector<Message*> msgVect; // Can hold the derived class object pointers
```

Process messages - You can perform operations on all the stored objects using a single loop.

```
for (auto msg: msgVect)
{
    // msg is pointer to the derived class objects stored earlier.
    // You can invoke a method here to perform operations on the
    // object.
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution! Storing unused variables in one class is obviously a bad design.

Comment: This passed through my mind , but the things is I have 20 message types and making 20 classes containing specified attributes .. I was taking it as a smart solution

Answer (score 0):

I would try Constructor Overloading.Constructor can be overloaded in a similar way as function overloading.

Overloaded constructors have the same name (name of the class) but different number of arguments.

Depending upon the number and type of arguments passed, specific constructor is called.

Comment: Overloaded constructors do not reduce the amount of class member variables

Comment: Yes, but they create only objects which is needed, which you passed (without remaining empty atributes).

Comment: It still allocates the memory for all variables, regardless of whether they are initialized or not

Comment: Ok, thank you for info.  I was think that unused constructors are simply passed, and only constructor with matched (needed) arguments create objects for only that arguments (not all possible ones).